# Security Implications in Electron as a Web Browser

Tags: node.js, security, browser, webview, electron

I asked this question a little over a week ago on the Atom forums (link below), and didn't receive a response, so I am reposting it here in the hopes that someone may be able to provide insight on my problem.

---

Recently, I have taken up an open source project which uses Electron as it’s front-end. This project has two requirements: it must be cross-platform, and it must have an embedded web browser (which should be able to browse the web and render content like a typical browser). Considering the rather large footprint Electron has already netted my application, it seems like a bad idea to attempt to use another embedded web framework alongside it. So, in the interest of simplifying my project and retaining the UI built on top of Electron, I am looking into using Electron itself as the web browser. Here’s where I’ve come into a problem.

In a security page for Electron’s documentation, it is explicitly stated that,

> it is important to understand … Electron is not a web browser

This quote comes within the context that Electron–or rather the code running on top of it–carries the unique ability to interact with the user’s operating system, unlike typical web applications. The page goes on to say,

> displaying arbitrary content from untrusted sources poses a severe security risk that Electron is not intended to handle

At this point, I was tempted to give up on the idea of using Electron as an inbuilt browser, but further down on that same page, you can find another very interesting tidbit:

> To display remote content, use the `<webview>` tag or `BrowserView` , [and] make sure to disable the `nodeIntegration` and enable `contextIsolation`

Link: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content

First, in regard to using webviews, Electron’s own documentation recommends outright avoiding them:

> Electron’s `webview` tag is based on Chromium’s `webview` , which is undergoing dramatic architectural changes. This impacts the stability of `webviews` , including rendering, navigation, and event routing. We currently recommend to not use the `webview` tag and to consider alternatives, like `iframe` , Electron’s `BrowserView` , or an architecture that avoids embedded content altogether.

Link: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag

Seeing as though I cannot avoid embedded content, I opted to look into using a BrowserView, but what I found was not very motivating either. The advice, as it stands, is to do two things:

- disable `nodeIntegration`
- enable `contextIsolation`

After looking at the security and best-practices page, I will also append the following steps:

- deny session permission requests from remote content (webcam, microphone, location, etc.)
- catch `webview` elements in creation and strip default privileges
- disable the creation of new windows
- disable the remote module

That is a fair amount of steps to undergo in securing external content. Not to mention, there were several additional warnings scattered through the best practices page such as the following:

(On verifying webview options before creation)

> Again, this list merely minimizes the risk, it does not remove it. If your goal is to display a website, a browser will be a more secure option.

Link: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#11-verify-webview-options-before-creation

(On disabling the `remote` module)

> However, if your app can run untrusted content and even if you sandbox your renderer processes accordingly, the remote module makes it easy for malicious code to escape the sandbox and have access to system resources via the higher privileges of the main process.

Link: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#15-disable-the-remote-module

Not to mention, upon navigation to the `BrowserView` page, the whole class is listed as experimental.

This all isn’t even to mention the added attack surface created by Electron, such as a vulnerability in the `webview` component just last year: CVE-2018-1000136

Now, taking into account all of the above, numerous developers have still opted to create web browsers that routinely consume external and uncontrolled content using Electron.

Browser’s using Electron (linked directly from Electron’s website):

- https://electronjs.org/apps/wexond
- https://electronjs.org/apps/dot
- https://electronjs.org/apps/beaker-browser

To me, it seems irresponsible to submit users to the above security implications as a trade-off for convenience.

**That being said, my question is: can you safely, to the point at which you could ensure the integrity of your users, implement web browsing capabilities for uncontrolled content using Electron?**

Thank you for your time.

---

Link to the original post:
https://discuss.atom.io/t/security-implications-in-electron-as-a-web-browser/70653

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas that don't fit into a comment box:

> [the project] must have an embedded web browser

So I presume then that this project isn't *just* a web browser. There's other content there that may have access to Node, but you just want the embedded-web-browser portion of it to be sandboxed appropriately, right?

Regarding the comments about `<webview>`, yes, it is considered unstable and Electron recommends using a `BrowserView` instead. I don't think that the fact that it's marked as "experimental" should necessarily deter you from using it (especially considering that the Electron team is recommending it [though maybe as the best of two evils]).

Experimental doesn't imply it's unstable. It can just mean that the Electron team is experimenting with this approach, but this approach may change in the future (at which point I would expect Electron to provide a transition path forward). Though this is one possible interpretation and ultimately Electron would have to comment on this.

> The advice... is to do two things:
>
> - disable nodeIntegration
> - enable contextIsolation

I would also make use of the [`sandbox` option](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) inherited from `BrowserWindows`. [`BrowserView's` docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view#new-browserviewoptions-experimental) on the constructor options say:

> `webPreferences` Object (optional) - See BrowserWindow.

which tells me that `BrowserView` accepts the same options as `BrowserWindow`.

You would set it up like so:

```
new BrowserView({ webPreferences: {
    sandbox: true,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    contextIsolation: true,
    preload: "./pathToPreloadScript.js"
}});
```

See more information about this approach [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option). The preload script is what would expose some Node IPC APIs to the sandboxed content you're loading. Note the [Status section](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option#status) at the bottom, which says:

> Please use the `sandbox` option with care, as it is still an experimental feature. We are still not aware of the security implications of exposing some Electron renderer APIs to the preload script

If the content you're loading in the `BrowserView` never needs to communicate back to the application, then you don't need a preload script at all and can just sandbox the `BrowserView`.

> After looking at the security and best-practices page, I will also append the following steps:
>
> - deny session permission requests from remote content (webcam, microphone, location, etc.)
> - catch webview elements in creation and strip default privileges
> - disable the creation of new windows
> - disable the remote module

Sure, those sound reasonable. Note that if your embedded browser needs to be able to open new windows (via `window.open` or `<a target="_blank" />`) then you'd have to allow popups.

> That is a fair amount of steps to undergo in securing external content.

Sure, but is your main concern with the security of the app, or with how much work it takes to make it secure? Browser developers need to consider similar things to ensure webpages can't get access to the OS. It's just part of the game.

> > Again, this list merely minimizes the risk, it does not remove it. If your goal is to display a website, a browser will be a more secure option.

This is just saying that if *all* you're trying to do is display a website, then just use a browser since that's what they're there for.

If you need to do other things, well then you can't use a browser, so you'll have to make your own app, making sure it's *reasonably* secure.

I think that if you follow what's recommended in the Security document and keep up to date with new Electron releases, then you're doing the best you can do.

As for whether that's good enough, I can't say. It depends on what you're developing and what you're trying to protect against.

However, my thoughts can't substitute the more expert opinions of those on the Electron team. This question could certainly use some guidance from them.